# How to disable the lockscreen /extend timeout windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep, display-settings, lock-screen

So I think if I disable all non-microsoft services (which also disconnects me from the internet) the console lock display timeout/system unattended sleep timeout finally stops locking after 2 minutes

I've tried setting both settings to 90 min but it times out much faster unless I disable all non-microsoft services including intel hp internet sound etc

Have a

HP  LAPTOP-4TSL8KPJ
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz   2.11 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.81 GB usable)
Device ID   9EEE07E5-D485-4F8E-9B13-D46EF5B002D1
Product ID  00325-81517-08523-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Touch support with 10 touch points

Comment: Update BIOS, Chipset, Video, Power Management, and Network Drivers with the HP Driver Update App. Restart, update Windows to current (updates this week), restart again and test. No lock screen timeout issues here on my own machines.

Comment: @John is there an app that updates your drivers or do you just download the latest drivers from the hp site?

Comment: Try this site here:  https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/bph07165

Comment: @John according to HP support assistant the software and drivers are up to date although does that include bios?

Comment: Look in the HP Support site for your exact model (be sure it is exact) and download the BIOS.  See if it looks different than the driver app or is the same. If BIOS and Power Drivers are up to date, then we need to engage in Windows Repairs.

Comment: Bios and Power should be up to date as far as HP support assistant is telling me.

Comment: If everything in the way of drivers is all up to date, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.

Comment: @John What does that do? will I need to reinstall programs and get my files back?

Comment: A Repair Install with Keep Everything will normally not lose anything but it is always a good idea to have data backup.